# JSF render component if exist

Tags: ajax, jsf, components, render, uicomponents

I have a question about rendering components.

I have the typical shopping cart bar that is a jsf component with a pop up where you can see the cart elements that you want to buy (cartBar.xhtml) and you can delete this elements from this popup.

Then I have two xhtml pages, one is the cart summary (cartSummary.xhtml) and another is the items catalog (catalog.xhtml).

In the cartSummary.xhtml and in cartBar.xhtml I have a button that removes a cart item. So if I delete it from the cartSummary I have to render a cartBar UIComponent to refresh the shoppingCart and cartSummary too. That works perfectly.

But if I try to delete the item from the cartBar (popup) I have in the delete button, a render property that refers to cartSummary.xthml because I need that the item dissapears from there too. The problem is, when I try to navigate to catalog.xhtml a view error appears telling me that the cartSummary.xthml UIComponent which is in the cartBar render can't be located.

I'll try with some code.

cartBar.xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="cartItemsPopup" styleClass="row" layout="block">
     //Code to show elements
     <h:commandButton value="Delete">
          <f:ajax listener="#{shoppingCartBean.deleteItem(cartItem)}" render="@form :cartItemBlock" />
     </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

cartSummary.xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="cartItemBlock" styleClass="row" layout="block">
     //Code to show elements
     <h:commandButton value="Delete">
          <f:ajax listener="#{shoppingCartBean.deleteItem(cartItem)}" render="@form :cartItemsPopup" />
     </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGroup>
```

When I click on cartBar.xhtml h:commandButton and then I navigate to catalog the error says :cartItemBlock cant be located which is true because is a UIComponent from cartSummary.

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: How is the bar being included into the summary? (And where)

Comment: Are these two pages displayed in the same view at the same time e.g. using templates or are they separate views?

Comment: Yes, the bar is in a header template.